# Subclassing in IB

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder, subclassing

I have UIScrollView added to the main window of the app with IB. 
What I want is that view to subclass UICustomScrollView instead of UIScrollView. To do that I choose the UIScrollView and then I change Custom class to UICustomScrollView in identity inspector. I have put some NSLog messages in init method of UICustomScrollView. When I run the app UICustomScrollView seem like it is not used because NSLog messages in init are not printed.

What I miss here ?

Comment: When a view comes out of a nib, `initWithCoder:` is called instead of `initWithFrame:`. Have you accounted for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what the [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) has to say about `initWithFrame:`:

> If you use Interface Builder to design your interface, this method is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. Objects in a nib file are reconstituted and then initialized using their `initWithCoder:` method, which modifies the attributes of the view to match the attributes stored in the nib file.

If your `NSLog` is only in `initWithFrame`, it won't be called if the view is loaded from a nib.